# TextAlignment using paint object android

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, canvas, paint

Iam drawing text using canvas and using paint object,trying to alignment my text to left,right and center and passing that object while drawing text on my canvas but found text alignment is aligning assuming x,y coordintes to whole canvas i think but i want to align my text withing my xposition and ypostion which iam setting while drawing text,can anyone please help me on this issue.

**Tried solutions:**
I tried by created rectangle with by x,y positon as bounds and get that bound with paint object and drawn text on canvas but it doesnt resolved by problem.Then i tried with created staticlayout ,passed paint object to that staticlayout and set my text on it and drawn to canvas ,that also given fix for my issue.

```
printdesignconroller:
          

     for (headerSegment in headerSegmentList) {
            var textPaint = TextPaint()
            textPaint = TextControl(textPaint).setTextProperties(headerSegment)
            if (headerSegment.shouldPrint) {
                when (headerSegment.colType) {
                    LABEL -> {
                        if (printProfileDetail.formName != PRE_PRINT) {
                            if (!shouldHideProperty(headerSegment, headerSegmentList, printModel)) {


                                canvas.drawText(headerSegment.colName, (headerSegment.xPosition * mmToPixelConvertorValue).toFloat(), (headerSegment.yPosition * mmToPixelConvertorValue).toFloat() + pageTop, textPaint)
                            }
}
}
```

TextControl:

```
fun setTextProperties(segment: PrintFieldDetail): TextPaint {
    paint.isAntiAlias = true
    if (segment.fieldPosition != "Detail") {
        paint.textSize = segment.fontSize.toFloat() + 3
    } else {
        paint.textSize = segment.fontSize.toFloat() + 2

    }
    if (segment.textAlignment == PrintDesignController.LEFT) {
        val align = Paint.Align.LEFT
        paint.textAlign = align
    }
    if (segment.textAlignment == PrintDesignController.RIGHT) {
        val align = Paint.Align.RIGHT
        paint.textAlign = align
    }
    if (segment.textAlignment == PrintDesignController.CENTER) {
        val align = Paint.Align.CENTER
        paint.textAlign = align
    }
    if (segment.textBold) {
        paint.typeface = Typeface.create(segment.fontName, Typeface.BOLD)
    }
    if (segment.textItalic) {
        paint.typeface = Typeface.create(segment.fontName, Typeface.ITALIC)
    }
    return paint
}
```

Comment: A [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help you get an answer faster and of better quality

Comment: I had given my code which can help people and give solution